# Approah on creating clients/realms for separate service (frontend and backend)

Tags: keycloak, quarkus, keycloak-rest-api

I'm new to keycloak and would like to check what is the common design on the said architecture.
I have 1 backend(quarkus) 1 frontend (angular) and 1 flutter.

I would like to see if I could leverage the features of client. My idea is to have a separate client within the realm. For example

**REALM** = MyAppRealm

**Client** = backend-client and front-endclient

Is it possible that the token i got from front-endclient can be use to access the api from the backend?

Reason I have this setup is that the front-endclient has a **public** accesstype while the backend has **confidential**

to sum up. I would like to see if i can reuse the token i got from **front-endclient** to my **backend-client**

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course you can do that.

The purpose of openid is to share authentication and authorization between a diversity of clients without needing to share credentials (no password is known by any of the clients). A trusted third party (here Keycloak) will give back a signed token in exchange for credentials. And this token will be a proof of who the user is and what he is allowed to do in the communications between the frontend and backend.

To sum up :

1. Your angular frontend authenticates an user using a public client and an implicit flow. When successfully authenticated, the frontend obtains an access token and a refresh token.
2. When making a REST call to the backend, your frontend needs to set the header Authorization using the access token as a bearer token ('Authorization: Bearer insert access token here'). You can automate this by using an interceptor ([example](https://www.illucit.com/en/angular/angular-5-httpinterceptor-add-bearer-token-to-httpclient-requests/))
3. Finally, when your backend receive an API request it can check the Authorization header to ensure the request is authenticated and authorized. For how to do that with Quarkus, everything is explained in this documentation page : https://quarkus.io/guides/security-openid-connect